# Get href list under HTML content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `json string` which contains HTML element. What I am trying to achieve is to fetch all anchor tag value `<a>` in that string.

**`Json String`**

`"content" : "<p>Reference information</p> <ul> <li><a href="https://myurl.com">My Url</a></li> <li><a 
             href="https://yoururl.com">Your Url</a></li> </ul>"`

Here is HTML Format

```
<p>Reference information</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://myurl.com">My Url</a></li>
<li><a href="https://yoururl.com">Your Url</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried like this but cannot get exact value:

```
 <div id="TestDiv" hidden >
   </div>

 let anchor = document.getElementById("TestDiv").getElementsByTagName("li");
 anchor[0].innerHTML
```

I am getting this value

```
<a href="https://myurl.com">My Url</a>
```

But I want to get `https://myurl.com`

another way I tried which was closed though still has problem but don't want to use regex:

```
content.match(/href="([^"]*?)"/);
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Create an element
const el = document.createElement("div");

// set the inner HTML
el.innerHTML = `
<p>Reference information</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://myurl.com">My Url</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://yoururl.com">Your Url</a></li>
</ul>
`;

// grab all <a> tag
const nodeList = el.querySelectorAll("a");

// convert to array
const nodeArray = [...nodeList];

// map to href
const hrefs = nodeArray.map((a) => a.href); // ["https://myurl.com/", "https://yoururl.com/"]
```

Comment: This is the solution I am looking for, great way you shown. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the href attribute value using .href or using the getAttribute("href") method. However you are currently getting the li elements, but you want to instead get the anchor elements.

```
let anchor = document.getElementById("TestDiv").getElementsByTagName("a");

anchor[0].href;
```

To get all of the href's you will need to loop through the array of anchors.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
  anchor[i].href;
}
```

Comment: But cannot get exact value,lets see again

Comment: I am not following, if anchor[0] is giving you a valid a element why isn't this working?

Comment: Getting `undefined` for `anchor[0].href` have you test that? If yes please update the answer with full solution.

Comment: sorry I just realised you are getting the li not the a. Will update answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` like:

```js
var anchorUrls = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.anchors, (i) => i.href;
);
console.log(anchorUrls);
```